# how to set value to textbox in multiple textbox event keyup on the row selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multiple textbox in table and when I set an event keyup on a row an action will calculate the total as `item * weight` goods and this value set to textbox of the same row which is selected.

In this jquery on function calculateBerat => `$('input[name=newBeratItem]').eq(0).val(getItemBerat);`

I have some troubles can you please
help me to fix this problem. thanks.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $(".jmlItem").keyup(function () {  
        var idBarang = $(this).attr('id');
        var jmlBarang = $(this).attr('value'); 
        var beratBarang = $(this).attr('rel'); 
        var jmlBarangNew = $(this).val(); 
        calculateItem();
        calculateBerat(idBarang, jmlBarangNew, beratBarang); 
    }); 

    function calculateBerat(idBarang, jmlBarangNew, beratBarang) {  
        var ttlBerat = 0;
        var getItemBerat = jmlBarangNew * beratBarang;

        $('input[name=newBeratItem]').eq(0).val(getItemBerat); 
        //in this code, the value is only charged on the first line does not correspond to the selected row keyup event.
        //how to ensure that value is filled in the corresponding row keyup event?

        $(".newBeratItem").each(function() {                
            ttlBerat += parseFloat(this.value);                          
        });
        $("#isTotalBerat").html(ttlBerat.toFixed(2)); 
    }

    function calculateItem() { 
        var jmlItem = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".jmlItem").each(function() {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                jmlItem += parseFloat(this.value);
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0){
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }            
        });       
        $("#isTotalItem").html(jmlItem.toFixed(2)); 
    } 
});
</script>
<table style="text-align:center;">
<tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Berat</td>
    <td>Harga</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="IdBarang01" value="5" rel="0.3" class="jmlItem" size="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="0.3" value="0.3" class="oldBeratItem" disabled size="1" style="background-color:#A0A197;"/>
        <input type="text" name="newBeratItem" class="newBeratItem" size="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="5000" value="5000" class="oldHargaItem" readonly size="2" style="background-color:#A0A197;"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="IdBarang02" value="6" rel="0.6" class="jmlItem" size="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="0.6" value="0.6" class="oldBeratItem" disabled size="1" style="background-color:#A0A197;"/>
        <input type="text" name="newBeratItem" class="newBeratItem" size="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="10000" value="10000" class="oldHargaItem" readonly size="2" style="background-color:#A0A197;"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div id="isTotalItem"></div></td>
    <td><div id="isTotalBerat"></div></td>
    <td><div id="isTotalHarga"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the `closest` parent `tr` and find the required `input` and set the value using `val()` as follows,

```
function calculateBerat(idBarang, jmlBarangNew, beratBarang) {  
        var ttlBerat = 0;
        var getItemBerat = jmlBarangNew * beratBarang;

        $("#"+idBarang).closest("tr").find('input[name=newBeratItem]').val(getItemBerat); 
        //in this code, the value is only charged on the first line does not correspond to the selected row keyup event.
        //how to ensure that value is filled in the corresponding row keyup event?

        $(".newBeratItem").each(function() {                
            ttlBerat += parseFloat(this.value);                          
        });
        $("#isTotalBerat").html(ttlBerat.toFixed(2)); 
    }
```

Comment: it works, thank you mr @TechBreak ...  #have a nice day =)